# Allocating RAM to Minecraft isn't recognized

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to allocate more RAM to Minecraft using this method:

1. open launcher
2. launch options
3. enable advanced settings
4. edit JVM Arguments from

-

```
**[[-Xmx1G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M]]**
```

...to...

```
**[[-Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M]]**
```

[image]

Note that this profile is not modded.

When I checked the memory in-game, it hadn't changed (still says "Mem: 39% 101/**256MB**"):

[image: Mem: 39% 101/256MB]

I have 8GB RAM

Comment: Can you please remove everything modded related from this question? Tech support for modded Minecraft is off-topic here. Do I understand it correctly that your `Xmx` argument is ignored, no matter if modded or not? Also, how much RAM do you have?

Comment: @Fabian I have 8GB RAM. I think the argument is being ignored either way, but my game only crashes when I use mods, also, I edited my post and then realised it has already been edited. I tried to undo my edits but idk how. Is it ok like this?

Comment: If the game only crashes when Minecraft is modded, then I'm afraid we can't help.  We specifically do not help with modded tech support for Minecraft.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech support for modded Minecraft.  We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: Please edit your question to say that the argument gets ignored and remove all the stuff about modded Minecraft. Then it's an on-topic question.

Comment: Is it better like this? I don't think the mods are really the problem anyway since trying to allocate more RAM doesn't work for vanilla either.